# How to always print String at the center of the screen?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using libgdx for my game and I have a viewport of 360x630, the problem is that I am using FreetypeFont for my fonts and the size is set to 24, I don't know how many pixels is 24. So what I did is

```
width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
font.draw(batch, wc.string, width / 2 - string.length / 2, height / 2 - string.length / 2);
```

but the string length is always changed because the string is always changed too.

Answer (score 1):

bellow A work around I always use to center any text with changing size, I don't know if it's a good practice to add useless sciene2D table for the purpose, anyway here is the solution :

Create a table :

```
private Table table;
```

In your show/create methode ( depend on your libgdx version ... ) add the following :

```
table = new Table(skin); // if you have a skin or you leave it empty
table.setFillParent(true);
YourText = new Label("YourText", skin, "YourFont");
table.add(YourText).colspan(3).expandX().spaceBottom(50).row(); // you change 50 depend on your screen resolution till you get to the center
```

This will put your text in a cell/row and center it H/V depend on the screen of course.

In the create/show method dont forget to add the table to the stage :

```
stage.addActor(table);
```

Now in your render method your add the following:

```
stage.act(delta);
stage.draw();
```

Finally you have to dispose the stage because the GC don't do it for you ( a libgdx way to do GC stuff ), in your dispose method you add this :

```
stage.dispose();
```

Comment: and the string? where do I put it?

Comment: inside a lable like so yourString = new Label("Your Text", skin, "Font");